# sum of multiplication in a list of objects

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am new to python, I have a quite simple question.
how is it possible to use `sum()` to do the following code in one line

```
total= 0.0
for record in myList:
    a= record.a
    b= record.b
   total+= (a*b)
```

with `myList` a list of objects that each one contains two attributes `a` and `b`

I know we can do the following

```
sum([3,4,5]) == 3 + 4 + 5 == 12
```

but how to get the sum of multiplication?

Comment: so you want the numbers multiplied

Comment: Can you post what `myList` contains?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "list comprehension" mean? How does it work and how can I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
total = sum(rec.a * rec.b for rec in myList)
```

Note the missing `[...]` brackets, avoiding the spurious constructioon of an in-memory list through a comprehension, and instead passing the generator expression to `sum`.

You could also throw the kitchen sink of functional utils at this :)

```
from operator import mul, attrgetter
from itertools import starmap

total = sum(starmap(mul, map(attrgetter("a", "b"), myList)))
```